# AEM - Classic UI - Can we implement tooltip on Classic UI dialogue CQ widgets? If possible, how can we do it?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am working on *AEM Classic UI* and I want to add a checkbox widget inside dialouge and to add a tooltip on it. Is that possible to add a tooltip or on mouse hover text inside dialogue on cq widgets? If possible, how can we implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
The answer is NO. We can't implement direct tooltip inside  dialogue box.

But we can implement a short text that works like tooltip.
eg:
feildLabel = `<p title="Trust me! I am tooltip!!">Hover over me</p>`

Note: In the above example, the tooltip text will appear only if we place the mouse over the base text for more then 1 second. There is an delay for a second.

We can implement tooltip in classic UI. Here below I gave the node structure to implement that.

Node Structure:
=> nt:unstructured

- => tooltip

- ```
        jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
  ```
- ```
        autoHide = true(Boolean)
  ```
- ```
        title = title for tooltip
  ```
- ```
        text = text for tooltip
  ```